# MATLAB will not add additional plot to existing figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have been working on a little GUI in Guide to make plots for me to compare various bits of data. I have set up two buttons, one to make a new figure (works fine) and one to add to the last created figure. When I click it, it appears to do everything. No errors turn up. But nothing is drawn in the plot. The code for the second plot is below:

```
hold on

clear newParSet eps %Clear variables used for previous plot

load(fullfile(handles.targetDirTxt.String,...
    strjoin(strcat(handles.folders(handles.gaugesMenu.Value),'_',...
    num2str(handles.gaugesMenu.Value-1),'_',...
    num2str(handles.indexing(idx)),'_',...
    num2str(handles.metric(rho)),'_',...
    num2str(handles.threshold(th)))),...
    'parameters.mat'));

scatter(newParSet(:,2),newParSet(:,1), '.',...
    handles.colorList(handles.onPlot.Value),'DisplayName',plotLegend);

hold off
```

`newParSet` loads as expected. `handles.colorList` contains an array of strings like `['b' 'r' 'k' 'y']` so I don't use the same colour twice. I don't know if that could be causing issues. `handles.onPlot.Value` contains the right number. I have tried running the script without the colour parameter but it still doesn't work.

Is there anything obvious that I have missed? Apologies if it turns out this issue has been covered elsewhere.

Comment: Add `disp(newParSet(:,1:2))` before your `scatter` command, and see if all data is in place.

Comment: From debugging, I know `newParSet` is loading correctly. I think I know the issue now and will post a solution if it works.